# Prolog predicate check divisibility of numbers in a list

Tags: prolog

example

```
divisible([L1],X) :-
L1 mod X =:= 0.
```

query

```
divisible([4,6,8,7],2).
```

response

```
[4,6,8]
```

Any guidance?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
divisible([], _, []).
divisible([H|T], X, [H|T1]) :- H mod X =:= 0, divisible(T, X, T1).
divisible([H|T], X, T1) :- H mod X =\= 0, divisible(T, X, T1).
```

Answer (score 3):

You are going to need a three-argument predicate (input list, value to test for divisibility, and output list).  After that, think about the three cases: input list is empty, first element is not divisible by number, and first element is divisible by number.  You should be able to write three clauses, one for each of those, and get a correct predicate.

Comment: thanks. but what about the other elements in the input list? You only mention the first element

Comment: @user645785: Those are handled in recursive calls in the last two of the cases I mentioned.

Comment: I am new to prolog, how can you cycle through the values in a list? Any pseudo code?

Comment: Here's the second case: if the list is of the form `[H|T]` and `H` does not divide `D` (the second argument), you return the result of calling your same predicate on `T` and `D`.  The third one is similar except that you prepend `H` to the result.

Comment: Like: divisible([H|T],Y) :-
   T mod Y =:= 0.      But that doesn't work because T is a list itself

Answer (score 2):

SWI-Prolog has a nice predicate `include/3` which you can use like this:

```
?- include(divides(2), [4, 6, 8, 7], L).
L = [4, 6, 8].
```

given that you have defined `divides/2`:

```
% Succeeds if X divides Y
divides(X, Y) :-
    Y mod X =:= 0.
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [meta-predicate](/questions/tagged/meta-predicate)  [`tfilter/3`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30211229/4609915) in tandem with the [reified test predicate](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13664870/4609915) `divisor_of_t/3`:

```
?- tfilter(divisor_of_t(2),[4,6,8,7],Zs).
Zs = [4, 6, 8].
```

Based on [clpfd](/questions/tagged/clpfd) and [`bool01_truth/2`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29459595/4609915), we can define `divisor_of_t/3` as follows:

```
:- use_module(library(clpfd)).

divisor_of_t(Y,X,Truth) :- X mod Y #= 0 #<==> B, bool01_truth(B,Truth).
```