# Sum of even, product of odd numbers in Prolog

Tags: list, prolog

I have a list of numbers, I need to calculate the sum of the even numbers of the list and the product of the odd numbers of the same list. I'm new in Prolog, and my searches so far weren't successful. Can anyone help me solve it ?

```erlang
l_odd_even([]). 
l_odd_even([H|T], Odd, [H|Etail]) :-
    H rem 2 =:=0,
    split(T, Odd, Etail). 
l_odd_even([H|T], [H|Otail], Even) :-
    H rem 2 =:=1,
    split(T, Otail, Even).
```

Comment: Can you show what you've already tried?

Comment: First, you need to make an attempt. I understand you're new to Prolog, but what have you learned so far about Prolog? Since you're dealing with *a list of numbers* you'll want to manipulate a list. You can Google "prolog list processing" and get some good information on how to manage lists. For starters, `[]` is the empty list, and `[H|T]` is a list with first element `H` and *rest* of the list (the *tail*) is `T`.

Comment: well this is my code so far "l_odd_even([]).
l_odd_even([H|T], Odd, [H|Etail]) :- ((H rem 2)=:=0), split(T, Odd, Etail).
l_odd_even([H|T], [H|Otail], Even) :- ((H rem 2)=:=1), split(T, Otail, Even)." I just don't know hot to implement the sum and the product after this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a suggestion for the sum of the even numbers from a list:

```erlang
even(X) :- 
  Y is mod(X,2),       % using "is" to evaluate to number
  Y =:= 0.

odd(X) :-              % using even
  Y is X + 1,
  even(Y).

sum_even(0, []).       % empty list has zero sum
sum_even(X, [H|T]) :- 
  even(H),
  sum_even(Y, T), 
  X is Y+H.
sum_even(X, [H|T]) :- 
  odd(H),
  sum_even(X, T).      % ignore the odd numbers
```

Note: My Prolog has oxidized, so there might be better solutions. :-)

Note: Holy cow! There seems to be no Prolog support for syntax highlighting (see [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/184108/what-is-syntax-highlighting-and-how-does-it-work)), so I used Erlang syntax. 
Ha, it really works. :-)

Running some queries in GNU Prolog, I get:

```erlang
| ?- sum_even(X,[]).    
X = 0 ?     
yes

| ?- sum_even(X,[2]).   
X = 2 ? 
yes

| ?- sum_even(X,[3]).    
X = 0 ? 
yes

| ?- sum_even(X,[5,4,3,2,1,0]).    
X = 6 ? 
yes
```

The ideas applied here should enable you to come up with the needed product.

Answer (score 2):

Use [clpfd](/questions/tagged/clpfd)!

```
:- use_module(library(clpfd)).
```

Building on [meta-predicate](/questions/tagged/meta-predicate) `foldl/4`, we only need to define what a *single* folding step is:

```
sumprod_(Z,S0,S) :-
   M #= Z mod 2,
   rem_sumprod_(M,Z,S0,S).

rem_sumprod_(0,Z,S0-P,S-P) :- 
   S0 + Z #= S.
rem_sumprod_(1,Z,S-P0,S-P) :- 
   P0 * Z #= P.
```

Let's fold `sumprod_/3` over the list!

```
l_odd_even(Zs,ProductOfOdds,SumOfEvens) :-
   foldl(sumprod_,Zs,0-1,SumOfEvens-ProductOfOdds).
```

Sample query:

```
?- l_odd_even([1,2,3,4,5,6,7],Odd,Even).
Odd = 105,
Even = 12.
```

---

Alternatively, we can define `sumprod_/3` even more concisely by using [`if_/3`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27358600/4609915) and [`zeven_t/3`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29459595/4609915):

```
sumprod_(Z,S0-P0,S-P) :-
   if_(zeven_t(Z), (S0+Z #= S, P0=P),
                   (P0*Z #= P, S0=S)).
```

Answer (score 1):

untested!

```
sum_odd_product_even([], S, P, S, P).
sum_odd_product_even([H|T], S0, P0, S, P) :-
    S1 is S0 + H,
    sum_even_product_odd(T, S1, P0, S, P).

sum_even_product_odd([], S, P, S, P).
sum_even_product_odd([H|T], S0, P0, S, P) :-
    P1 is P0 * H,
    sum_odd_product_even(T, S0, P1, S, P).

sum_odd_product_even(L, S, P) :-
    sum_odd_product_even(L, 0, 1, S, P).

sum_even_product_odd(L, S, P) :-
    sum_even_product_odd(L, 0, 1, S, P).
```

Comment: So, the product of nothing is 1?

Comment: @Boris: yes, the neutral element of multiplication.

Comment: I am not sure, but I _think_ that what you are sort of getting at is the sum and product of numbers at even and odd _positions_, but it seems that OP is trying to get the sum and product of even and odd _numbers_.

Answer (score 0):

It shouldn't get much simpler than

```
%
% invoke the worker predicate with the accumulators seeded appropriately.
%
odds_and_evens( [O]      , P , S ) :- odds_and_evens( [] , O , 0 , P , S ) .
odds_and_evens( [O,E|Ns] , P , S ) :- odds_and_evens( Ns , O , E , P , S ) .

odds_and_evens( []       , P , S , P , S  ) . % if the list is exhausted, we're done.
odds_and_evens( [O]      , X , X , P , S ) :- % if it's a single element list, we've only an odd element...
  P is X*O ,                                  % - compute it's product
  .                                           % - and we're done.
odds_and_evens( [O,E|Ns] , X , Y , P , S ) :- % if the list is at least two elements in length'e both an odd and an even:
  X1 is X*O ,                                 % - increment the odd accumulator
  Y1 is Y+E ,                                 % - increment the even accumulator
  odds_and_evens( Ns , X1 , Y1 , P , S )      % - recurse down (until it coalesces into one of the two special cases)
  .                                           % Easy!
```